# Trying to render functional component after ajax request?

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, react-hooks

**UPDATE**:  Error was due  `[project, setProject] = useState(null);` instead should be `const [project, setProject] = useState({});` ***Can't initialize state to null throws error... I thought render `<p> loading </p>` would trigger... that I don't why doesn't trigger.***

I want to render my component once ajax requests has successfully grabbed data i.e. `project object`. I'm using `useLayoutEffect` to synchronously do this ajax request in.

However i'm getting the

> **TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasksNumber' of undefined**

**How do I fetch data first, then render component?**

```
function EditProjectView(props) {
  const [project, setProject] = useState(null);

  // get id from params
  const id = useParams();

  // after renders it will use this hook
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // fake* ajax request to database
    const data = database.projects.find((project) => {
      return project.id == id;
    }, []);

    setProject(data);

    console.log("Let's see:", project);
  });

  const projectView = (
    <React.Fragment>
      <main style={classes.content}>
        <div style={classes.projectContainer}>
          <div style={classes.projectOverviewWrapper}>
            <Paper elevation={2}>
              <div style={classes.project}>
                {<ProjectDetailsView project={project} />}
              </div>
            </Paper>
          </div>
          <div style={classes.tasksContainer}>
            <h3>
              ALL TASKS
              {project.tasksNumber} <---------------- here?
            </h3>
            <TaskExpansionPanel
              panelTitle={<PanelTitle />}
              panelDetails={<PanelDescription />}
            />
            <CreateTaskBtn />
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );

  return project !== null ? (
    <LayoutGrid view={projectView} />
  ) : (
    <p>loading...</p>
  );
}

export default EditProjectView;
```

**database.js**

```
var database = {
  projects: [
    {
      id: 1,
      projectName: "Write a book",
      tasksNumber: 15,
      startDuration: new Date().toDateString(),
      endDate: new Date().toDateString(),
      projectCreator: "joe",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      projectName: "Code an app",
      tasksNumber: 4,
      startDuration: new Date().toDateString(),
      endDate: new Date().toDateString(),
      projectCreator: "Samir",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      projectName: "Finish Assignment",
      tasksNumber: 12,
      startDuration: new Date().toDateString(),
      endDate: new Date().toDateString(),
      projectCreator: "Potter",
    },
  ],
};

module.exports = database;
```

Comment: apparently, `database.projects.find` returned undefined. Can you show us `database.projects`?

Comment: @NicholasTower added database.js in question..

Comment: What about the id from useParam? Can you log that?

Comment: useParam isn't logging, nice catch. However even with hardcoded       return project.id == 1;
same error?

Comment: ok i got it. can't can nulls   const [project, setProject] = useState(null); instead should be   const [project, setProject] = useState({});

Comment: Anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that effects run after the component rendered, hence at first render the state is null.

**update**

In your case using `useLayoutEffect` is not necessary, you can replace it with `useEffect`.

useEffect is called with this sequence:
React renders your component > Browser paint > useEffect()

useLayoutEffect instead is called like so:
React renders your component > useLayoutEffect() > Browser paint

```js
<h3>
     ALL TASKS
     {project ? project.tasksNumber : "Loading..."}
</h3>
```

Comment: I'm using useEffectLayout. Isn't it synchronous though? Runs before render and after no?

Comment: Plus its not rendering loading... its through an error

Comment: Revert the initial state back to `null`

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'tasksNumber' of null
 it says...

Comment: Actually because of how you structured the code, you should not need the change I proposed. Let me see if I can reproduce the error.

Comment: What was the issue?

Comment: Error was due  `[project, setProject] = useState(null);` instead should be `const [project, setProject] = useState({});` ***Can't initialize state to null throws error... I thought render `<p> loading </p>` would trigger... that I don't why doesn't trigger.